# Is that valid CSS?

Tags: css

I was reading through an article about position sticky in CSS and saw this line of CSS code:

```
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
```

What are those * signs? Is the above CSS valid?

Comment: The * sign selects all the element inside .main-container